# Prevent react and reselect from sorting items

Tags: reactjs, sorting, redux, render, reselect

I am using React and Redux. I have a store of items like `{name: 'Jim', votes: '5', type: 'candidate'}`

I am using reselect to get a filtered list of items. I am also using reselect to sort this list of items by votes.

When an item is voted it will automatically change position in the list (item changes, reselect does its job and reorder the list).

I would like to prevent this behavior. Is that possible without re-ordering inside the state?

Comment: You have to show some code!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach might consist of **generating the sorting information** during data **normalization** or items **initialization**. You might keep the information into a separate array or just push a `sorting` propery into each item object.

In that way updating the score wouldn't interfere with item sorting.

Comment: So you would fetch the API on every resort? Or maybe create a normal state (un-ordered) and an ordered state that gets it's sorting property updated when the ordering selector is changed. I think I see how this can work

Comment: I'd be inclined toward the second option. In general data normalization is the right time to do this kind of operations.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could introduce a new property in the Redux state like `shouldSort` which you initialize to `true`. Then, in your `updateVote(newValue)` action (or what ever you call it), you let the reducer for that action also set `shouldSort` to `false`.

Now you could use `shouldSort` in your reselect function to determine if it should or shouldn't sort.

Note that you would also need to reset the state of `shouldSort` when you enter/leave the page. Or else you may not get a sorted list when you leave and enter the page again.

Comment: If `shouldSort` is false, wouldn't reselect send the non sorted list (ie not sorted by votes anymore)? Maybe I have to implement that logic + store the earlier order in state?

Comment: Yeah that's probably right.. didn't think of that. Yeah, storing the previous state would solve it. But it doesn't feel like a very clean solution.

Comment: How about letting the Redux state reflect/determine how the view should look? So you take reselect out of the picture. You sort the array by votes by default (first time you get/set the data in state). Then when you change votes, you simply leave the order untouched. If you leave and re-enter the page, you run the "get/set" action again, and it will be sorted (taking the new vote into account). To me that feels cleaner. But I also get why it would make sense to let a selector worry about the sorting, because it's some kind of transformation that is specific to how the component wants the data.

Comment: Yes, I thought about sorting the array by votes directly in the state but I'm not sure it is clean and I'm using a [normalized state](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html). The state slice that is displayed (`allItemIds`) doesn't know about the number of votes and is thus hard to re-order. It seems there is no easy way to do it without changing the state structure...

Comment: Yeah, sounds hard. Maybe you'd have more luck if you posted a new question asking specifically about how to do this with normalized data. I haven't used the normalized approach before but it seemed like there was a solid theory behind it. Maybe someone with more experience will have an answer. Good luck either way!